# Group chats and private chats, seperate table or single table with type attribute?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I have a table users, a table chats, however I want there to be "Group chats" and "Private chats (dm)".
A group chat needs more data than a private chat, such as for example: Group name, picture, ....

What is the best way to approach this?
Do I make 1 table chats, and put a type attribute in there that deteremines if it is private or not and leave some columns blank if it is a private chat. OR Would I make 2 tables one for private chats, and one for group chats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar scenario to the general question *"should you split sensitive columns into a new table"* and the general answer is the same, it is going to depend largely on your data access code and your security framework.

What about a third option, why not just model a `Private Chat` as a `Group Chat` that only has 2 members in the group?. Sometimes splitting the model into these types is a *premature optimisation*, especially in the context of a *chat* style application. For instance, couldn't a *private chat* benefit from having an image in the same way that a *group chat* does? Could there not be some benefit to users being able to specify a *group name* to their own private group?

You will find the whole development and management of your application a lot simpler if there is just one type of *chat* and it is up to the user to decide how many people can join or indeed if other people can join the chat.

If you still want to explore the 2 conceptual types this is this is an answer that might give you some indirect insights: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74398184/1690217 but ultimately we need additional information to justify selecting one structure over the other. Performance, Security and general data governance are some considerations that have implications or impose caveats on implementation.

From a structural point of view, your `Group Chats` and `Private Chats` can be both implementations of a common `Chat` table, conceptually we could say that both forms *inherit* from `Chat`.

In relational databases we have 3 general options to model inheritance:

- **Table Per Hierarchy (TPH)**
  Use a single table with a *discriminator column* that determines for each row what the specific *type* is. Then in your application layer or via views you can query the specific fields that each type and scenario needs.

  - In **TPH** the *base* type is usually an *abstract* type definition
- **Table Per Type (TPT)**
  The *base* type and each concrete type exists as their own separate tables. The FK from the inheriting tables is the PK and shares the same PK value as the corresponding record in the *base* table, creating a 1:0-1 relationship. This requires some slightly more complicated data access logic but it makes it harder to accidentally retrieve a `Private Chat` in a `Group Chat` context because the data needs to be queried explicitly from the correct table.

  - In **TPT** the base type is itself a *concrete type* and data records do not have to *inherit* into the extended types at all.
- **Simple Isolated Tables** *(No inheritance in the schema)*
  This is often the simplest approach, if your tables do have inheritance in the application logic then the common properties would be replicated in each table. This can result in a lot of redundant data access logic, but the OO inheritance in the application layer following **DRY** principal solves most of code redundancy issues.

> This answer to [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579462/1690217) covers DB inheritance from a more academic and researched point of view.

From a *performance* point of view, there are benefits to isolating *workloads* if the usage pattern is significantly different. So if `Group Chats` have a different usage profile, either the frequency or type of queries is significantly different, or the additional fields in `Group Chat` would benefit from their own index profiles, then splitting the tables will allow your database engine to provide better index management and execution plan optimisations due to more accurate capture of table statistics.

From a security and compliance point of view, a single table implementation (**TPH**) can reduce the data access logic and therefore the overall attack surface of the code. But a good ORM or code generation strategy usually mitigates any issues that might be raised in this space. Conversely **TPH** or simple tables make it easier to define database or schema level security policies and constraints.

Ultimately, which solution is *best* for you will come down to the effort required to implement and maintain the application logic for your choice.

I will sometimes use a mix of **TPT** and **TPH** in the same database but often lean towards **TPT** if I need inheritance within the data schema, this old post explains my reasoning against **TPH**: [Database Design: Discrimator vs Separate Tables with regard to Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11968767/1690217). My general rule is that if the *type* needs to be *polymorphic*, either to be considered of both *types* or for the *type context* to somehow change dynamically in the application runtime, then **TPT** or *no inheritance* is simpler to implement.
I  use **TPH** when the differences between the types is minimal and not expected to reasonably diverge too much over the application life time, but also when the usage and implementations are going to be very similar.

**TPT** provides a way to express inheritance but also maintain a branch of vastly different behaviours or interactions (on top of the *base* implementation). many **TPT** implementations look as if they might as well have been separate tables, the desire to constrain the 1:1 link between the records is often a strong decider when choosing this architectural pattern. A good way to think about this model, even if you do not use *inheritance* at the application logic level, is that you can *extend* the base record to *include* the metadata and behaviours of any of the inheriting types. In fact with TPT it is hard to constrain the data records such that you cannot extend into *multiple* types.

- Due to this limitation, TPT can often be modelled from the application layer as not using OO Inheritance at all
- TPT complements *Composition* over *Inheritance*

**TPH** is often the default way to model a *Domain Model* that implements simple inheritance, but this introduces a problem in application logic if you need to change the *type* or is incompatible with the idea that a single record could be *both* types. There are simple workarounds for this, but historically this causes issues from a code maintenance point of view, it's a clash of concepts really, TPH aligns with *Inheritance* more than *Composition*

In the context of *Chat*, **TPT** can work from a *Composition* point of view. All chats have the same basic features and interactions, but `Group Chat` records can have *extended* metadata and behaviours. Unless you envision `Private Chat` having a lot of its own specific implementation there is not really a reason to extend the base concept of `Chat` to a `Private Chat` implementation if there is no difference in that implementation.

For that reason too though, is there a need to differentiate between *Private* and *Group* chats at all from a database perspective? Your application runtime shouldn't be using blind `SELECT *`  style queries to access the data in either case, it should be requesting the specific fields that it needs for the given context, whether you use a *Field* in the table, or the *Name* of the table to discrimate between the different concepts is less important than being able to justify the existence of or the difference between those concepts.

Comment: Thankyou for thorough explanation, and for explaining me terms I had never heard about, but now know about :)

Comment: I guess the real answer to your question is that if this is your _"Hello World, I'm a Developer"_ project, then you should try this a number of ways. Really try to fully implement the application, then compare your experience. To see the performance difference will take a very large load of data so you won't easily see that, but for most other aspects the schema for a simple scenario like this is the trivial element. All the strategies discussed here are valid, it is your data access logic that will guide you on choosing a specific implementation.